# android in onPreviewFrame method of image distortion . I will save the image to the SDcard in the following picture

Tags: java, android

**Camera image data：**

```
PreviewCallback previewCallback = new PreviewCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            synchronized (nv21) {
                System.arraycopy(data, 0, nv21, 0, data.length);
                isNV21ready = true;
            }
        }
    };
```

**save image：**

```
public void decodeToBitMap( byte[] data, int mindex, int camera)
{

        try {

            Bitmap mBitmap = null;
            Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
            int format = parameters.getPreviewFormat();
            if (format == PixelFormat.YCbCr_420_SP || format == PixelFormat.YCbCr_422_I) {
                int w = parameters.getPreviewSize().width;
                int h = parameters.getPreviewSize().height;
                int[] i = new int[data.length];
                decodeYUV420SP(i, data, w, h);
                mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(i, w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            } else if (format == PixelFormat.JPEG || format == PixelFormat.RGB_565) {
                mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
            }
            if (mBitmap != null) {
                try {
                    Bitmap mbitmap = STUtils.getRotateBitmap(mBitmap, -90);
                    String face_path = getDirPath()+"/facecache/"+String.format("%04d.jpg", mindex);
                    PicUtils.saveBitmap(face_path, mbitmap);
                    mbitmap.recycle();
                    mbitmap = null;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mBitmap.recycle();
                mBitmap = null;
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logg.e(TAG, TAG + "decodeToBitMap Error:" + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

**Image transfer format：**

```
public void decodeYUV420SP(int[] rgb, byte[] yuv420sp, int width, int height) {

    final int frameSize = width * height;
    for (int j = 0, yp = 0; j < height; j++) {
        int uvp = frameSize + (j >> 1) * width, u = 0, v = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++, yp++) {
            int y = (0xff & ((int) yuv420sp[yp])) - 16;
            if (y < 0)
                y = 0;
            if ((i & 1) == 0) {
                v = (0xff & yuv420sp[uvp++]) - 128;
                u = (0xff & yuv420sp[uvp++]) - 128;
            }
            int y1192 = 1192 * y;
            int r = (y1192 + 1634 * v);
            int g = (y1192 - 833 * v - 400 * u);
            int b = (y1192 + 2066 * u);
            if (r < 0)
                r = 0;
            else if (r > 262143)
                r = 262143;
            if (g < 0)
                g = 0;
            else if (g > 262143)
                g = 262143;
            if (b < 0)
                b = 0;
            else if (b > 262143)
                b = 262143;
            rgb[yp] = 0xff000000 | ((r << 6) & 0xff0000) | ((g >> 2) & 0xff00) | ((b >> 10) & 0xff);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know why, but the error is only on the part of the phone.
For example xiaomi 5 phone.Please look at the wrong picture.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUBzV.png)